# how to format JSON to fit the schema for EON Pubnub charting Library

Tags: python, list, concatenation, pubnub

I am struggling with this for quite some time now, can someone explain a solution to this problem

```
if i = {'x': 123, 'y': 456} {'x': 675, 'y': 098}
```

turn it into

```
message: {
      columns: [
        ["x": 123, "y": "456"],
        ["x": 675, "y": 098]
      ]
```

**More Insights:**

I have the following Data structure

```
[<OldSample {u'counter_name': u'cpu_util', u'user_id': u'id', u'resource_id': u'id', u'timestamp': u'2015-06-30T15:53:55', u'counter_volume': 0.043}]
```

I need to make it something like this to put in EON pubnub charting libaray (see link: http://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/chart/spline/)

```
message: {
      columns: [
        ["y": 0.043, "x": "2015-06-30T15:53:55"],
        ["y": 0.045, "x": "2015-06-30T15:53:55"]
      ]
```

Now I have the following code

```
def get_clean_Json(data):
  for each in data:
    timestamp = each.timestamp
    volume =  each.counter_volume
    i = {'x': timestamp, 'y': volume}
    print i
```

Which returns results like this

```
{'x': 123, 'y': 456} {'x': 675, 'y': 098}
```

and I am stuck here, no matter what I do I get errors

Comment: Provide more insights

Comment: Neither what you seem to be saying you have, nor what you say you want are valid Python syntax. Try fixing your question to show valid Python data structures and someone may be able to answer.

Comment: Should `i` be a list of dictionaries and lose the if?

Comment: Please provide a runnable example with the outcome you get now and provide the expected output in valid Python syntax.

Comment: @PaulRooney maybe but there's no real way to tell from that what they want as the target data structure.

Comment: @VigneshKalai Complete explanition above

Comment: @PaulRooney explanation above

Comment: @AlainO'Dea runnable example above

Comment: @lmo u cann't do dictionary with in list initially you could initialize message like this `message={"column":[]}`  then after print i you could do this `message["column"].append(i.items())` with in for loop

Comment: @VigneshKalai yea I tried that already it creates none type objects

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can publish the EON data in any format from the back end and transform it on the front end using javascript. See the `transform` parameter here:
https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart#quickstart

And an example here:

https://github.com/pubnub/eon-chart/blob/master/examples/transform.html

Comment: I am actually getting the data through an openstack python API that is why I want to publish this data via python, makes things easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

List concat in python is just `[]+[]`, but it doesn't seem that this is what you are looking for. 
What you are actually seeking here is how to format your JSON to fit the schema that EON requires.

(This is one of the reasons you've been downvoted multiple times! So make sure to ask a right question!)

Try

```
coords = []
def get_clean_Json(data):
  for each in data:
    timestamp = each.timestamp
    volume =  each.counter_volume
    i = {'x': timestamp, 'y': volume}
    coords.append( i )
get_clean_Json(your_data)
message = {
    columns : coords
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar solution before but it returns none, tried your code above as well it throws the error columns : coords
NameError: name 'columns' is not defined

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion about correcting the question, fully agreed. I am actually going nuts trying to solve this issue.